# "Closed as duplicate" description in revision history is worded awkwardly

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, revisions-list

I noticed that the "Closed as duplicate" entry that's appended to a question's revision history is worded (IMHO) rather awkwardly. [An example](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/40963/revisions) of the current phrasing is:

> **Post Closed** as "exact duplicate" by eldarerathis♦ of
>
> - How to remove apps from “all downloaded” in Play Store

Having the names of the closers come right before "of" is just...strange sounding. I felt almost as though I was being granted some sort of knightly title, though I think going by the name "eldarerathis of How to remove apps from 'all downloaded' in Play Store" is a bit verbose for my liking.

My suggestion would be to simply shuffle the wording a little bit to something like:

> **Post Closed** by eldarerathis♦ as "exact duplicate" of
>
> - How to remove apps from “all downloaded” in Play Store

...which helps maintain the association of "exact duplicate" and its preposition.

Comment: I'd think it would be better to have "**Post closed** as exact duplicate of ... by some closer names".

Comment: @DanielFischer: The only reason I suggested the wording I did was because of a bit of a concern about how that might break the formatting (but yours is also an entirely logical phrasing). Either would be preferable to the current one.

Comment: Actually, I think the formatting would be more stable if you have the closers on a new line after the dupes. Imagine "Post closed by FiveUsersWithAwkwardlyLongAndVerboseOneMightSayAbundantlyRedundantDisplayNames as exact duplicate ...", that would put too much stuff between the "closed" message and the reason, IMO. But your suggestion reads less awkwardly than what we have now for sure.

Comment: And, by the way, "eldarerathis of How to remove apps..." is an awesome title. You should wear it proudly.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sadly, it exceeds the username character limit...and here I thought I had found the perfect Meta display name.